# iOS strange keyboard-hiding behavior when adding a subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, core-animation

I have a view with an `UITextField` and need to show an `UIDatePicker` (it's hidden below the keyboard) when a button is pressed.

I'm lazily instantiating the date picker because this allows me to show the view way more fast.

This is the code associated with the tap on the button:

```
- (IBAction)hideKeyboard {
    if (!self.datePicker) {
        // UIDatePicker allocation and initialization
        self.datePicker = ...
        ...
        [self.view addSubview:self.datePicker];
    }
    [self.textField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

What happens is that this interfere with the keyboard hiding animation. Actually there is no animation at all.

Another clue I have is that this doesn't happen on the simulator, but only on the actual device (an iPhone 4S).

How can I solve this?

**EDIT**:

Setting the datePicker as the `inputView` of the textField doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can recommend you another solution then hiding keyboard and using button for showing the date picker.

If I understood you correctly you want to show a date picker when user taps on the textfield and then maybe you set the date in textfield.

UITextField has a property

> @property (readwrite, retain) UIView *inputView

If you set the inputView property to date picker then the textfield will show date picker instead a keyboard (and even animated like keyboard).

Of course the values need to get your own and set to textfield.

Edit reason: Question edited

I do not know why setting the datepicker as the input view did not help. Anyway if you do not want the keyboard shown and show the datepicker by adding a subview you can use the following delegate method of UITextField

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
```

implement the delegate method. In the method just add pickerview as subview to your view and return NO for not to show the keyboard.

Edit reason: Commend

Is there any reason why you do not use textfield? If not I would use it, because it makes everything easier. If you want to use for some reason the UILabel then you can watch the keyboard notification. When did the keyboard disapeared and then show the datepicker.

For keyboard notifications please refer here, good explained with sample codes, UIKeyboardDidHideNotification should help you

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html

Comment: Didn't knew about this! It is not what I was asking for, but maybe it can solve the problem even better.

Comment: The datePicker does not modify the value of the textField (but of a label (my choice)), this is the reason the inputView method was not helpful

Answer (score 0):

Quite simple :

Just add a date picker object as the input value of your textfield. No need to show/hide the keyboard.

```
UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar] ;
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init] ;
[comps setYear:anyInteger];
NSDate *maximumDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:currentDate options:0];
[comps setYear:anyInteger;
NSDate *minimumDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:currentDate options:0];
[datePicker setMaximumDate:maximumDate];
[datePicker setMinimumDate:minimumDate];
datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
textField.inputView = datePicker;
```